# How to access MySQL from MPI program (use MPICH2)?

Tags: c++, mysql, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I have huge database (DBMS = MySQL) that I access from an MPI program (using MPICH2). In this program, I just want to know about time to execute sql query. It's reference to my other parallel program.

When the code's run from Visual Studio C++, it runs well (I get the output). But when it's runed use `mpiexec`, there's no output and no error message. Otherwise, when I try a simple program (no mysql code, use mpiexec), it runs well (there is output). Should I not be using the mysql and mpi libraries together?

The code like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//namespace for error handling
namespace ekception{
        struct error{
        const char *p;
        error(const char *q){
        p=q;
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MYSQL mysql,*sock;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    int state;
    char *host="localhost";
    char *user="root";
    char *password="";
    char *dbName="sp";
    double start,finish,time;
    long j;
    char s[]="SELECT COUNT(kolom2) FROM coba WHERE kolom1<=";
    char query[BUFSIZ];

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    for(j=250000;j<=25000000;j+=250000){
    sprintf_s(query,"%s%d",s,j);
    start=MPI_Wtime();
    try{
        mysql_init(&mysql); 
        if(!(sock=mysql_real_connect(&mysql,host,user,password,dbName,0,NULL,0))){
            throw ekception::error("Connection failed\n");
        }
        mysql.reconnect=1;

        state=mysql_query(sock,query);

        if(state!=0){
            throw ekception::error("Query execution Failed\n");
        }

        res=mysql_store_result(sock);
        mysql_free_result(res);
        mysql_close(sock);
    }

    catch(ekception::error e){
        printf("%s\n",e.p);
    }

    finish=MPI_Wtime();
    time=finish-start;
    printf("Data size = %d *** time = %f\n",j,time);
}

MPI_Finalize();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This might be stupid, but I still have to ask... You have `localhost` as your server name. Are processes started with `mpiexec` also running on `localhost` or are they sent to some backend compute nodes?

Comment: yes, i use localhost as my mysql server. yes, i try it on localhost only (just 1 PC).

Comment: Could you try to remove the `getchar()` call at the end of `main()`? Console input doesn't play well with MPI.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following :

1. add following to see whether you are `really` running in the MPI framework :

   ```
   int id, nprocs;

   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);

   printf("Sql Init from proc %d out of %d!\n", id, nprocs);
   ```

I would print the rank ID as part of all your log statements so as to identify from which MPI child process the print statement is commencing from .

2 .  Just to be sure , i would rather check the return type of `mysql_init(&mysql);`

3 . for debugging purposes  you can add a `getchar()` just after the `MPI_Init()` call so that both processes (assuming that the `mpirun/mpiexec` number of processes argument is 2) are launched. You can then see in the MVS `attach debugger` window , the processid's of both the processes. Then you can attach a debugger to one of the MPI child process and see what is failing in the `sql` query execution for a given mpi child process .

4 . not sure why you need to open/close the `sql socket` inside your for loop. ? it can be outside the `for` loop.

5 . cross check whether your program is realy linking with appropriate mpi lib.

Comment: Hi Jay D,thanks for your answer. my program has link with mpi library. I need to know total time's needed to access database, that whay open/close sql socket inside loop. Now I try simple program(executed by mpiexec). Before it added by mysql_init(), all run well. But when it's added, output's blank.

Comment: this is the simple code:

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <mpi.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <mysql.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <winsock.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
 int proc,id;
        MYSQL mysql;
 MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc);
 printf("Sql Init from proc %d out of %d!\n", id, proc);
        mysql_init(&mysql);
 MPI_Finalize();
 getchar();
 return 0;
    }

Comment: try this : `#include <stdio.h> 
#include <mpi.h> 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <mysql.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <winsock.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
int proc,id, mysqlretval = 0; 
MYSQL mysql; 
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc); 

printf("Sql Init from proc %d out of %d!\n", id, proc); 
fflush(stdout);
getchar(); 


mysqlretval = mysql_init(&mysql); 

printf("Sql Init returned %d from proc %d out of %d!\n", mysqlretval, id, proc); 
fflush(stdout);



MPI_Finalize(); 
return 0; 

} `

Comment: mysql_init() has 'MYSQL *' return value, so we can't save into integer. If I change mysqlretval type,it's same. the program run well from visual studio/just double click the executable file but not from mpiexec. <I really really don't know what's wrong>

Comment: sorry, i missed the return value. we need to check if the return value is `null` then. i strongly suspect that it is `null`

Comment: when I print out mysqlretval, there is not null.

Answer (score 0):

1. We can use mysql and mpi library together, that's true.
2. At this problem, maybe caused huge data(but I'm not sure about that). Maybe size of MYSQL_RES which's used save data from mysql query not enough.